# El método validarIngreso(int, String) en el tipo Coordinador no es aplicable para los argumentos (int, char[])

Tags: java, eclipse, login

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de Java Login de usuario en vídeo, donde existen 2 ventanas Principal y Login, ademas de controlador "Coordinador".
En la ventana Login en el método actionPerformed, tengo el siguiente if:

```
if(evento.getSource()==btnAceptar) {
        String resp=miCoordinador.validarIngreso(cmbUsuario.getSelectedIndex(),cmpPass.getPassword());
        
        if (resp.equals("error")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No ha seleccionado un usuario");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, resp);      
            miCoordinador.cerrarVentanaLogin();
        }
    }
```

validarIngreso Eclipse la marca con rojo, al poner el Mouse encima sale lo siguiente:
The method validarIngreso(int, String) in the type Coordinador is not applicable for the arguments (int, char[])

con las siguientes opciones:
Cambiar el método 'validarIngreso('int String)' a validarIngreso(int, char[])'

Crear método 'validarIngreso(int, char[])' en tipo 'Coordinador'

El metodo esta creado en el Coordinador, es el siguiente:
public String validarIngreso(int index, String pass) {

```
    return miLogica.validarIngreso(index, pass);
}
```

Por ende la opción Create method 'validarIngreso, ya existe, y si cambio String por char[], Eclipse deja de marcar el error. Pero el botón aceptar no funciona.

¿Como puedo solucionar este inconveniente?

Comment: El propio error te está diciendo exactamente lo que pasa. Tu variable `pass` es un `char[]` y necesitas que sea un `String`... Por ejemplo usando `String.valueOf(pass)` en el parámetro en vez de pasar solo `pass`. Es difícil decirte exactamente como/donde ponerlo si no vemos el código entero relacionado con la pregunta. En cuanto a "Si cambio String por char[] no funciona" ... claro que no funciona, seguramente estás usando un `JPasswordField` o como se llame, y haciendo el `getText()` sin más, eso devuelve `char[]`. Probaste a añadirle un `toString()` ahí a continuación por ejemplo?

Comment: Gracias @Benito-B, si estoy usando `private javax.swing.JPasswordField cmpPass;` hice lo recomendado y al parecer esta funcionando